# What is this ninja anime from the late 70s early 80s?

Tags: manga-sarutobi-sasuke

I have seen this anime on TV as a child, dubbed in Arabic (so I couldn't tell you what the character names are). This was during the early 80s and I don't recall much of the detail.

The protagonist is a boy, always dressed in a red kimono and long black hair tied up and armed with a katana.

As a ninja he was able to transform to different animals (I recall a very large fish).

Wish I had more details, but it was long ago and in a language I did not understand.

Comment: you really dont remember anything more?

Comment: @Robin - I was 10. The people were all wearing short kimonos and the bad guys also had swords. I think (!?) there was some small creature that was the companions protagonist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the series *[Manga Sarutobi Sasuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_Sarutobi_Sasuke),* or *Ninja, The Wonder Boy*.

The show tells the story of Sasuke, a Koga ninja boy living in 17th century Japan, doing battle with the Iga ninja clan lead by the evil Hanzo.<sup>[1](http://www.maxtoons.com/Sasuki.htm)</sup>

[image: Nin nin!]

OP/ED: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b7vnd8rhoY

Comment: Nicely done! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.